# Multiple methods in single codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, methods

I need to store data from textboxes, which are in different `aspx` pages, (9) all of them share the same "codebehind". In c# btw.

This is a 'curriculum vitae' like form, which has 9 sections, all of them need to be stored in the same db.

I already have methods for a single one, but i need to create nine methods, to store these textboxes, every time a user clicks in btn 'save'. And then go to the other page `postbackurl`.

I need for example to store data like this:

```
ConexionGeneralDataContext db = new ConexionGeneralDataContext();

Usuario_Web columna = new Usuario_Web();

columna.Estatus = 1;
columna.Fecha_hora = DateTime.Now;
columna.Nombre = nombre.Text;
columna.Email = userEmail.Text;
columna.Trabaja_opcion = sies.Text;
columna.Trabaja_opcion = noes.Text;
columna.Apellido = Apellidos.Text;
columna.Em_solicitado = Empleo.Text;
columna.DireccionPersonal.Text;
columna.Ciudad = Ciudad.Text; ...
```

But i don't know if i need to declare this on the `master page` too.

Also, every method should be called from a `button ID`, with the `OnClick` event. And add the `postbackurl` attribute to store data, and then pass to the next page.

Could anyone point me to some example or tutorial with some similar circumstances?

EDIT

The problem i have is that i did not develop the first page, so this first one has an `if` statement, and this statement should work for just two pages, not all of them;

```
if (validFile)
{
    ConexionGeneralDataContext db = new ConexionGeneralDataContext();

    Usuario_Web columna = new Usuario_Web();

    columna.Estatus = 1;
    columna.Fecha_hora = DateTime.Now;
    columna.Nombre = nombre.Text;
    columna.Email = userEmail.Text;

    columna.Trabaja_opcion = sies.Text;
    columna.Trabaja_opcion = noes.Text;
```

The file just goes in two pages, not all of them.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking, are you asking if this approach is a good idea? Since you have one of the nine done, why not just do the other eight the same way?

Comment: Sure, well i made an edit to my question, i hope i've explained myself.

Comment: Also, it is good to declare this postbackurl attribute this way? :

Comment: 'Response.Redirect("page.aspx");'

Comment: No, this is a crazy idea. ASPX pages aren't meant to work this way. You should look into using user controls, and the Wizard control. Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Hi, i'm using 4.0, i'm not an expert into asp, do you know some better approach to this?

Comment: I think i can use some similar approach to the code already written, but it's kinda tricky though

Comment: Just to be clear, `Response.Redirect` does not post data to the next page.  Pull your code out of the page and into a class file in the App_Code directory, so you can use it in different pages or in different wizard steps with ease.  You will need to give us some more information on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok, gonna open a new question :) thx @ps2goat